# Cannot perform CRUD operations to database in the Cloud from Android?

Tags: php, android, mysql, google-cloud-storage

I recently migrated my database from localhost the Google Cloud. I followed [this](https://www.apachefriends.org/docs/hosting-xampp-on-google.html) tutorial as it suited my needs best (was running XAMPP previously).

So now I have a LAMP instance running in the Cloud. In my config.php I have;

```
/**
 * Database config variables
 */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "xxxxx");
mysqli_select_db($link, "db");
```

This config setting is correct.
When I attempt to (e.g login) I receive JSON back but it is never the correct response and always avoids the select/insert/update statements in the PHP (they work fine running locally).

I have been stuck on this for a couple of days now, any input appreciated!